# Laravel Eloquent getting value from previous relation/pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a bunch of results coming from eager loading through many to many relations. I need to filter one thing, I have this output :

```
"id_stats":32,
"n_stats":"Mastery",
"image_stats":null,
"pivot":{  
   "id_equipement":11,
   "id_stats":32,
   "weight":"235",
   "rand-elem":"3"
},
"elements":[  
   {  
      "id_elements":2,
      "n_elements":"Feu",
      "pivot":{  
         "id_stats":32,
         "id_elements":2,
         "id_equipement":15
      }
   },
   {  
      "id_elements":3,
      "n_elements":"Eau",
      "pivot":{  
         "id_stats":32,
         "id_elements":3,
         "id_equipement":13
      }
   }
]
```

I must filter the equipement on pivot(parent).id_equipement = elements.id_equipement otherwise I will have the result of the whole table. I can either filter my result like this. I already tried to add an inner join in my belongsToMany relation but it didn't help!

Here is parts of my code:

EncyclopedieModel.php

```
public function stats(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(StatsModel::class, 'equipement_stats', 'id_equipement','id_stats')
        ->withPivot('weight')->withPivot('random');
}
```

StatsModel.php

```
public function elements(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(ElementModel::class, 'stuff_equipement_stats_elements', 'id_stats', 'id_elements')
        ->withPivot('id_equipement');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: why not just write raw query and get what You need? isn't it will be more performant?

Comment: I thought about it but I will have to write 4 or 5 queries and create the input myself. There are 4 tables to go through! I was looking for the possibility with Eager Loading

Comment: Do You retrieve just one `EncyclopedieModel` item? if Yes You can just use example from here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-query-pivot-table-where-clause

Comment: I retrieve many EncyclopedieModel item, then I retrieve StatsModel item based on many EncyclopedieModel item, then I retrieve ElementsModel item basde on many StatsModel item.

Comment: Oh then for that case I recommend to use raw query, otherwise it's query heavy operation to db.

Comment: I will go for that then! Is there a way to easily create my output when I have all my queries? I must have a single response at the end

Comment: or You can just get encyclopedie items with stats, and then loop items to get id_equipment and then just call `$equipments = EquipmentsModel::whereIn('id_equipments', $equipment_ids);` then just merge data using php

Comment: I Will Go for that then, thanks for help!